# Using window operators but with concating column values on a partition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is what my input looks like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | TypeA | V1 |
| A | TypeA | V2 |
| A | TypeB | V3 |
| A | TypeB | V4 |
| A | TypeA | V5 |
| A | TypeA | V6 |
| B | TypeA | V7 |
| B | TypeB | V8 |

This is my expected output:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | TypeA | V1,V2 |
| A | TypeB | V3,V4 |
| A | TypeA | V5,V6 |
| B | TypeA | V7 |
| B | TypeB | V8 |

I have tried thinking of doing this with window operators but haven't been successful in coming up with a solution yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below.

```sql
SELECT columnA, columnB, STRING_AGG(columnC, ',' ORDER BY columnC) AS columnC FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY columnC) part FROM (
    SELECT *, columnB <> LAG(columnB) OVER (PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY columnC) flag
      FROM sample_table
  )
) GROUP BY 1, 2, part;
```

**Query results**

[image]

- Assuming that `columnC` is an ordering column. If your table has an another ordering column, you can use that instead.